# How to align multiple image div from center?

Tags: html, css

I have 4 image div at the moment . And i want them to start aligning from the center . So that if anyone add more image div future it automatically align to the center.
Is it possible ?

Comment: no, it's not possible. Because we don't have any html, any initial effort. It's surely impossible.

Comment: I can't see those "4 image div"

Comment: @CarlJan maybe you need to imagine those, don't use your eyes, use your brain. Well this technique is fairly hard. Imagining and guessing are usually not easy.

Comment: @KingKing What I mean for that is how he constructed those divs

Comment: @Fiido no thats not what i want. I need tobalign div for owl carousal or bootstrap not slidibg carousel. For example i have 6 logo that i can show in owl carousal as a slider and that will cover up the whole space now when i have only 3 logo. It show on the left side of tge page . But i want them to be centered. And when more logo will be added it automatically align from the center rather then align on the left side. I hope this make sense ty

Answer (score 2):

use grid template provided by bootstrap and set the parent as container.

HTML

```
<div class="container">

<div class="col-md-3">
<img src="https://pmcvariety.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/beauty-and-the-beast-trailer.jpg?w=1000&h=563&crop=1" alt="disney">
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
<img src="https://pmcvariety.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/beauty-and-the-beast-trailer.jpg?w=1000&h=563&crop=1" alt="disney">
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
<img src="https://pmcvariety.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/beauty-and-the-beast-trailer.jpg?w=1000&h=563&crop=1" alt="disney">
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
<img src="https://pmcvariety.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/beauty-and-the-beast-trailer.jpg?w=1000&h=563&crop=1" alt="disney">
</div>

</div>
```

As I understand this is what you want?

[Full Layout](http://jsfiddle.net/h4begr91/embedded/result/)

Comment: what a nice mind reader? Because the OP did not explain his problem very well. So it's great if any mind reader (like you) could translate the OP's words into something meaningful and clear (about the actual problem). Such as this ***i want them to start alinging feom the center***, and this ***if anyone add more image div future it automatically align to the center***? So your demo at least need to  reflect those scenarios of the OP.

Comment: Please don't ask back to the question giver with some question like ***Is this that you want?*** - That means the answerer still doesn't  understand the question giver thoroughly. Such kind of question should be put as comment only. BTW, I would say something better like ***As I understand this is what you want***. That sounds a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible just you can try below code.

```
<div class ='container'>
   <div class ='container-inner'>
      <div class ='image'>
        <img src=''>
      </div>
      <div class ='image'>
        <img src=''>
      </div>
      <div class ='image'>
          <img src=''>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>

  <style>
   .container{
     width:100%:;
   }
  .container -inner{
     display: table;
    margin:auto;
 }
.image{
   float : left;
}
 </style>
```

Above code helps you to put all image container to center.
If you add single image to it it take only that width which is image width and align center, if more images take width according as align center.